# clear array while inside loop javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, cron

I have this loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            let sessionString = rows[i][weekday];
            //finalSessionString is the variable for splitting the string into 4 parts
            const finalSessionString = sessionString.split('|');
            //finalSessionString0 is the string that holds the value of (ex) 01 11 * * 1
            const finalSessionString0 = finalSessionString[0]
            //finalSessionStringPhoneNumber gets phone number from finalSessionString
            const finalSessionStringPhoneNumber = finalSessionString[1]
            //finalSessionStringName is getting the name of the person training
            const finalSessionStringName = finalSessionString[2]
            //finalSessionStringTrainerName is getting the name of the trainer
            const finalSessionStringTrainerName = finalSessionString[3]
            console.log("kk: " + finalSessionString[1])
            console.log(finalSessionString0)
            console.log(finalSessionStringPhoneNumber)
            console.log(finalSessionStringName)
            console.log(finalSessionStringTrainerName)
            var textJob = new cronJob( finalSessionString0, function(){
                client.messages.create( { to: finalSessionStringPhoneNumber, from:'12055578708', body:'hello ' + finalSessionStringName + ', Your training session just finished with ' +  finalSessionStringTrainerName}, function( err, data ) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("err: " + err)
                    } 
                    console.log(data)
                });
            },
            null, true)
            finalSessionString.length = 0
        }
```

finalSessionString is an array, that produces a response like so:

```
 [
  '05 10 * * 2',
  '1234567890',
  'Gianluca A',
  'gianluca@mmm.com'
]
```

so after i split up the array into multiple parts, I want it to clear the array length, because I am also running a cronjob which runs every 45 seconds, so every 45 seconds it is inserting a new value into the array! So after every time it inserts a new record into the array, I need it to clear it first. that's what I tried to do here

```
finalSessionString.length = 0
```

but it isn't working, because i got 5 text messages after 5 rounds of the cronjob running. So how can i fix this?

Comment: Setting the (read-only) length to zero won't work. You simply need `finalSessionString = []` (also, why do you call an array "finalSessionString"?)

Comment: you need to rethink the design, you shouldn't be adding a cronjob for every item in rows, but instead a single *cronjob* which then works on all items in rows

Comment: @ChrisG thanks. variable names are just temporary right now, but i agree they are terrible lol

Comment: @LawrenceCherone honestly I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around the concept in which I am trying to do, i know 100% it is not the right way to do it. If you're willing to help me find a better solution we could chat elsewhere?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804783/sending-text-to-incorrect-record-from-database-sql this is my other question that explains the whole situation. Maybe you could view that one please?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to clear the aray before the Cron job just do

```js
finalSessionString = [ ];
finalSessionString.push(value);
```

Comment: I used what you said. I appreciate your asnwer. I actually think it's another issue, i just can't figure it out. could you see my other question adn maybe i'm doing something wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804783/sending-text-to-incorrect-record-from-database-sql